# swift - UITableView section insets

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have design the screen like below image.

[image]

I wonder how I can inset margin in section like a blue area.

These are not cell spacing, header or footer height, layout margin.

Comment: Collection view is best option

Answer (score 0):

You could have the cell's `contentView`'s `backgroundColor` set to `clear` and setup your UI elements however you want. That way it'll look as if the cell is indented.

Comment: Sorry. My poor English made a misunderstanding. The color is just a example. I need a solution about section insets without using tricks(?)

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve by indenting the cells? Do you want to add some special behavior? Because if it's only about styling the table view, what I proposed should be enough. Otherwise I'll need more information about your end goals.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to inset your whole `TableView`/`TableViewCell`. Create a container View inside your TableViewCell instead. And set margin for inner `UIView`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't do it with UITableView. There is no API for section insets.